# Integrating Google App Invites with GA

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-app-invites

I have a question regarding process of Integrating App Invites with GA, described here: https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/analytics

I am not seeing any data in Analytics, and it has been over 4-5 days now. One thing to note is that in the Guide it is mentioned about Custom Dimensions the following: "Note that this dimension must be at Index 1 in the table of Custom Dimensions." But mine is set to Index 2 and I don't know how to change the index number.

I would like to know, if that might be the reason of not seeing the data. And if so, how do I change this Custom Dimension to Index 1?